# How to add window padding in NCurses?

Tags: ncurses

I have my window

```
WINDOW *win = newwin(40, 40, 3, 3);
```

When some text is entered and is spanning more lines, what is the best way to preserve the neat whitespace around the inner borders of the window? I cannot seem to find a way to give a window this kind of property in NCurses.

I guess a way to make padding is to create another window inside this one. There must be a cleaner way.

Comment: No, that's surely the cleanest way.

Comment: @WilliamMcBrine are you absolutely sure? There is no in-built function or technique to do this? I mean, is it used in professional applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

William McBrine is absolutely sure.  The simplest way to retain a box around a window is to create the box in a window which surrounds it.  That is because

- changes to the inner box have no effect on the box
- there is a function `box` which draws a box along the edges of a given window.

Several of the ncurses test-programs use this feature.  For instance, one of the menu entries in the main test-program (in `ncurses.c`) [responds to a **`w`**](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/master/test/ncurses.c#L886) by creating a window to hold the box, then a window to hold its contents, and draws a box in the former before continuing to accept input in the new inner box:

```
    } else if (c == 'w') {
        int high = getmaxy(win) - 1 - first_y + 1;
        int wide = getmaxx(win) - first_x;
        int old_y, old_x;
        int new_y = first_y + getbegy(win);
        int new_x = first_x + getbegx(win);

        getyx(win, old_y, old_x);
        if (high > 2 && wide > 2) {
            WINDOW *wb = newwin(high, wide, new_y, new_x);
            WINDOW *wi = newwin(high - 2, wide - 2, new_y + 1, new_x + 1);

            box(wb, 0, 0);
            wrefresh(wb);
            wmove(wi, 0, 0);
            remember_boxes(level, wi, wb);
            wgetch_test(level + 1, wi, delay);
            delwin(wi);
            delwin(wb);

            wgetch_help(win, flags);
            wmove(win, old_y, old_x);
            touchwin(win);
            wrefresh(win);
            doupdate();
        }
```